# How to edit Standard google maps activity fragment UI

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hey guys I'm new to android studio. I wanted to add buttons to the google maps activity fragment but for some reason, it's blocking me from doing that. I figured because its a fragment. I dont think any code is neeed cause i did not make any changes(just the standard google maps ativity). How can I change this to create let's say a button when clicked moves to a different screen. Or a toolbar under the map

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following code to my xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >
</FrameLaout>
```